# Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile - Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite, rubygems

Just started developing in Ruby on Rails. I can't seem to find any similar issues on Ubuntu on the web. My version of sqlite3 is 1.3.10. I have tried commenting out the sqlite3 from gem file and also updated the bundles. But I am still getting this error. I need sqlite3 in my application but I can't seem to figure out what is going on. Has anyone had similar issues and was able to fix it mind helping me get over this hump?

Thanks

Comment: Is "Add \`gem 'sqlite3'\` to your Gemfile" the error message you're getting? If it is, make that explicit in your post, it is currently unclear at the first sight what is the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

- Install it with:

  `sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev`
- Add `sqlite3` to your gem file
- `bundle install`
- cofigure your `database.yml` file

Comment: sqllite3 is already installed to its latest version and sqlite3 is added to gem file. I have done the above :/

Comment: Okay try just `rails new test`. It will make a new app that uses `sqlite3` by default.